# How to use one variable inside another in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab yaml file for running certain jobs. In the variables part, I have declared certain variables with values and when I try to use it in another variable formation, it is actually generating but not fetching in the later part of job execution.

Code tried is as below:

```
variables:
  env: "prod"
  user: "test"
  region: "us-east"
  var1: '$env-$user-$region'
```

As suggested in one forum to include *var1* formation in **before_script** script part.  I tried it, but it was also not returning the *var1* value correctly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the whole pipeline where var1 is not correctly resolved?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [this section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#create-a-custom-cicd-variable-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file) of the official documentation, they describe using variables within variables:

> You can use variables to help define other variables. Use $$ to ignore a variable name inside another variable:
>
> ```
> variables:
>   FLAGS: '-al'
>   LS_CMD: 'ls $FLAGS $$TMP_DIR'
> script:
>   - 'eval $LS_CMD'  # Executes 'ls -al $TMP_DIR'
> ```

I was able to follow this pattern, and additionally I was combining variables in the script: step with a command such as:

```
script:
  - APP_NAME=$APP_NAME-$VERSION
```